# Replace null with 0 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I am getting `NULL` values in the results of an operation in MySQL.

Is there a way to convert the `NULL` values into the value 0?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Yes, by using `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(null_column, 0) AS null_column FROM whatever;
```

COALESCE goes through the list of values you give it, and returns the first non-null value.

Comment: +1: `COALESCE` is ANSI, supported by SQL Server 2000+, Oracle 9i+, MySQL 4.1+, dunno the version of PostgreSQL or SQLite...

Comment: MySQL is mentioned in the title. I added a tag for it.

Comment: I think every 3VL DB with a SQL interface supports `coalesce()`. Case and point, [it was in MySQL 3.23](http://www.norrnod.se/norrnod/dokumentation/mysql/3.23.45/manual_toc.html#Comparison_Operators) which is about as close to the bottom of the barrel as you can get.

Answer (score 100):

**I am adding this answer because no one mentioned `IFNULL` function**

You can use [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
SELECT IFNULL(column_name, 0) FROM table_name;
```

`IFNULL` will return column's value (if it has something other than `NULL`) otherwise second parameter passed (in this case `0`).

Comment: Thanks, run perfect in mysql.

Comment: This only really selects and replaces, rather than truly updating the table

Comment: can i do it with multiple columns?

Comment: @XinNiu yes you can. `SELECT IFNULL(column1, column2) FROM table`. or `SELECT IFNULL(column1, 0) AS alias1, IFNULL(column2, 0) AS alias2 FROM table`. BUT if you want to use more than 2 columns in one expression then you will need to use `COALESCE` like this `SELECT COALESCE(column1, column2, column3, column4, 0) FROM table`. `COALESCE ` will return first non-null value in the parameters.

Answer (score 26):

If you messed up and have NULLs in existing table layout and want zeros, here is solution:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `somefield`=0 WHERE `somefield` is null
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: This is exatcly i wanted.. Thank you

Comment: I almost got tricked by the accepted answer. This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

There is the `COALESCE` method which return the first non-null parameter, in your case :

```
COALESCE(field, 0)
```

But you can use this if you want more :

```
COALESCE(field1, field2, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

MySQL:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Mycolumn, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the 0 value into your insert input method by casting it:`(int)0`