# Change Null with 0

Tags: mysql

I have tried to run a query I phpmyAdmin as follows

---

```
SELECT
  orders_history.id,
  orders_history.`items`,
  orders_history.`transaction_id`,
  orders_history.`quantity`,
  estockClaims.`esquantity`,
  IFNULL( esquantity, 0 ),
  orders_history.`quantity` - estockClaims.`esquantity` AS myquantity
FROM orders_history
LEFT JOIN estockClaims
  ON orders_history.transaction_id = estockClaims.transaction_id
 AND orders_history.items = estockClaims.items
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

---

And it gives me this result:

```
       ----------------------------------------------------------------------
       id     items      transaction_id    quantity   esquantity   IFNULL(esquantity , 0 )   myquantity
       1      FR               001           100        NULL              0                        NULL
       2      BR               002            10        NULL              0                        NULL
       3      WR               003            25        25               25                        0
       4      CR               004            50        3                 3                        47
```

How to solve this so that NULL is not NULL anyomre but change to 0. Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532776/mysql-replace-null-with-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have it in the next column. What you need to do is to drop the original `esquantity` column and make an alias for the `IFNULL...` column, like this:

```
SELECT orders_history.id, orders_history.`items` , orders_history.`transaction_id` , 
       orders_history.`quantity` , IFNULL( esquantity, 0 ) AS esquantity, 
       orders_history.`quantity` - estockClaims.`esquantity` AS myquantity
FROM orders_history
LEFT JOIN estockClaims ON orders_history.transaction_id = estockClaims.transaction_id
AND orders_history.items = estockClaims.items
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

The change I mentioned is in the line 2 above.

UPDATE

---

To get

```
orders_history.`quantity` - estockClaims.`esquantity` AS myquantity
```

to show expected results, you need to "unnullify" the `esquantity` field again so that the subtraction would work:

```
orders_history.`quantity` - IFNULL( estockClaims.`esquantity`, 0 ) AS myquantity
```

That would ensure you no longer get, for example:

```
100 - NULL
```

but this instead:

```
100 - 0
```

which will return a proper value.

You can also skip the whole subtraction thing if `esquantity` is NULL and simply use the value of `quantity`.

Comment: It works for the esquantity column. But why the result from the ` `orders_history.`quantity` - estockClaims.`esquantity` AS myquantity` ` is still NULL. What I want is it still the same with the first quantity.

Comment: Because you also need to use 0 there instead of NULL, I'll write you an update.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IF` to check the `esquantity` and `myquantity` columns:

```
IF(esquantity IS NULL, 0, esquantity)
```

and

```
IF(myquantityIS NULL, 0, myquantity)
```

or use `IFNULL` as DanFromGermany said

Comment: `IF (... IS NULL, ...)` is the same as `IFNULL( ..., ...);` + answer not helpful, where to use it?

Comment: I think you should actually ask the upvoter to explain why this answer got an upvote - @DanFromGermany explained it to you why it's completely not helpful (or should I say completely useless) because OP is already doing IFNULL... You should focus more on giving good answers rather chasing points. Btw, I'd say you should be happy you got an upvote for this, don't ask for more.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you are using it as select instead of when doing subtraction. Use it as below:

```
SELECT orders_history.id, orders_history.`items` , orders_history.`transaction_id` ,          orders_history.`quantity` , orders_history.`quantity` - IFNULL( esquantity, 0 ) AS myquantity
FROM orders_history
LEFT JOIN estockClaims ON orders_history.transaction_id = estockClaims.transaction_id
AND orders_history.items = estockClaims.items
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select temp.id, items, transaction_id, quantity, ifNULL(esquantity, 0), ifNULL(myquantity, 0)
from (SELECT
  orders_history.id,
  orders_history.`items`,
  orders_history.`transaction_id`,
  orders_history.`quantity`,
  estockClaims.`esquantity`
  orders_history.`quantity` - estockClaims.`esquantity` AS myquantity
FROM orders_history
LEFT JOIN estockClaims
  ON orders_history.transaction_id = estockClaims.transaction_id
 AND orders_history.items = estockClaims.items
LIMIT 0 , 100) temp
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you should always add an explanation, code-only answers are very likely to get downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **COALESCE** to replace the **NULL value to 0**

check this query.

```
SELECT orders_history.id, orders_history.`items` , orders_history.`transaction_id` , 
       orders_history.`quantity` , COALESCE( esquantity, 0 ) AS esquantity, 
       orders_history.`quantity` - COALESCE(estockClaims.`esquantity`, 0) AS myquantity
FROM orders_history
LEFT JOIN estockClaims ON orders_history.transaction_id = estockClaims.transaction_id
AND orders_history.items = estockClaims.items
LIMIT 0 , 100
```