# MySQL - Replace NULL or empty with 0000

Tags: mysql, string

I try to replace null value with string 0000

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.idc = c.id
WHERE deleted = 0
```

I try with

`IFNULL(c.customer_id,'0000')`

`COALESCE(c.customer_id,'0000')`

`REPLACE(c.customer_id,'','0000')`

but don't work.

Result should be:

```
(Before)    (After)
null        0000
1234        1234
            0000
```

What should I do ?

Comment: `COALESECE()` should be getting the job done.  Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL: replace null with 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532776/mysql-replace-null-with-0)

Comment: What the data in the tables? the query looks fine

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I update sample data.

Comment: @PathikVejani Should be same but in my case not return 0000 it return empty field

Comment: Do you have both null values and empty strings?

Comment: `SELECT IF(c.customer_id IS NULL OR c.customer_id = '', '0000', c.customer_id)` should work fine.

Comment: Well, next time pls make such details clear!

Comment: @Shadow Sorry :( I will do better next time, but I think my question might be clear with Replace NULL or empty phrase.

Comment: @h2ooooooo It's work :) thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline `IF` to check for null and empty strings and if exists then return `'0000'`.

```
SELECT IF(customer_id='' OR customer_id IS NULL,'0000',customer_id)
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.idc = c.id
WHERE deleted = 0
```

Comment: It's work and easy for me same as @h2ooooooo 's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN customer_id ='' THEN replace(customer_id,' ','0000')
WHEN customer_id is null THEN replace (customer_id,null,'0000')
end AS customer_id
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.idc = c.id
WHERE deleted = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check for empty first like this:

```
SELECT case when customer_id='' then '0000' else COALESCE(c.customer_id,'0000') end 
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.idc = c.id
WHERE deleted = 0
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I suspect the reason is that the OP is already essentially using your query and still did not get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both null values and empty strings, then you need to combine coalesce() with string replacement:

```
SELECT if(coalesce(customer_id,'0000')='','0000',coalesce(customer_id,'0000')) as customer_id
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.idc = c.id
WHERE deleted = 0
```