# MySQL Query LEFT OUTER JOIN AND IFNULL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have this query:

```
SELECT st.st_id, st.id, st.name, at.status, at.date
FROM st,at
WHERE st.st_id = at.at_id;
```

but I want the result return all of `st` table, if `st`.st_id exist in `at`.st_id, the status column is what in the `at` table, if not the status is 'H', anyone can help?
[this is my table column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zfbF.png)

Comment: What is the foreign key for `st` table in `at` table `at_id` or `st_id`? I ask you this question because I don't understand why you say `WHERE st.st_id = at.at_id;`

Comment: Hi. Please: Read about formatting code. [use text, not links/images, for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3404097). Please read & act on [mcve]. This is a faq and basic. Always google many clear, concise specific phrasings of your question/problem/goal without your application-specific names and read many hits; if you find no answer then use one phrasing as title. Read & act on [ask].

Comment: @PierreRobentzCassion One doesn't need to know FKs or any other constraints to query. Here we can just accept that they want status when st.st_id = at.at_id. It doesn't matter whether a FK could be or is declared between those columns or any other columns. (A FK could be declared when the referenced table is a PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL & the referenced column values are all in it.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace null with 0 in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532776/replace-null-with-0-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/*Use IFNULL if DB is MYSQL*/

```
SELECT st.st_id, st.id, st.name, IFNULL(at.status,'H') as status, at.date
FROM st LEFT JOIN
     at
     ON st.st_id = at.at_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Then it would be easier to write the query:

```
SELECT st.st_id, st.id, st.name, COALESCE(at.status, 'H') as status, at.date
FROM st LEFT JOIN
     at
     ON st.st_id = at.at_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

First let me try to understand what you want your query to do:

1. The query must all `st` where `st.st_id = at.at_id`
2. If `st.st_id = at.st_id` then `at.status = status` else `status='H'`

The script that I suggest:

`SELECT st.st_id, st.id, st.name,
IF(st.st_id = at.st_id, at.status, 'H') AS status, at.date
FROM st LEFT JOIN at ON st.st_id = at.at_id;`

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT   st.st_id,
            st.id,
            st.name,
            st.cl_id,
            st.gender,
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(at.st_id ) THEN 'H' ELSE at.status
   FROM `st`
   LEFT JOIN `at` ON `st`.`st_id` = `at`.`st_id`
```