# PHP mysql order by nullable date field

Tags: mysql

**Below query is providing result of 22 rows in my sql**

```
select pk.partnerid
     , pk.id as packageId
     , pk.name as package
     , p.partnername as partner
     , bp.name
     , bp.bookedDate
     , bp.email
     , bp.phone 
  from packages as pk 
  join bookpackage as bp 
    on bp.pkId = pk.id 
  left 
  join partner as p 
    on p.id = pk.partnerid 
 where pk.status > 0 
 order by (bookedDate is null) asc
     , bookedDate asc
```

**where as the same in application provides only 3 rows which has not null dates**

```
mysqli_query($con, "
select pk.partnerid
     , pk.id as packageId
     , pk.name as package
     , p.partnername as partner
     , bp.name
     , bp.bookedDate
     , bp.email
     , bp.phone 
  from packages pk 
  join bookpackage bp 
    on bp.pkId = pk.id 
  left 
  join partner p 
    on p.id = pk.partnerid 
 where pk.status > 0 
 order
    by (bookedDate is null) asc
     ,  bookedDate asc
");
```

**I want to show all data and order by date if date is not null.**

Comment: check bookedDate is null in where condition

Comment: Sorry its a typo mistake ..Updated on question..The output remains same

Comment: how many rows are there in db with bookedDate is not null

Comment: There are 3 rows and those rows are displaying in application.I want to show the other rows also

Comment: then remove statement bookedDate is null,so it will show all

Comment: No change!The output provides only 3 rows

Answer (score 0):

check bookedDate is not null in where condition

```
mysqli_query($con, "
select pk.partnerid
     , pk.id as packageId
     , pk.name as package
     , p.partnername as partner
     , bp.name
     , bp.bookedDate
     , bp.email
     , bp.phone 
  from packages pk 
  join bookpackage bp 
    on bp.pkId = pk.id 
  left 
  join partner p 
    on p.id = pk.partnerid 
 where pk.status > 0 
 and bookedDate IS NOT NULL
 order by bookedDate asc
");
```

Answer (score 0):

so if the date is null how it should be sorted?
as I understand form your question, you have only 3 records that have then date, the other dates are null
in case you need to sort those 3 then all the records, then you may choose 1 of the following solutions:

- convert all null to 0 in your db if possible, you can also make the field as not null, and it will be added as 0 automatically if not inserted
- you have an option in your query to replace null with 0, check this answer [Replace null with 0 in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532776/replace-null-with-0-in-mysql#answer-3532793)

Comment: Sorry to ask.What is the relevant if i do so?Will it retrieve all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

**ORDER BY** -bookedDate asc,  bookedDate asc

instead of

order
    by (bookedDate is null) asc
     ,  bookedDate asc