# Replace NULL to \N from mysql result

Tags: mysql, null

I need to replace `NULL` values to `\N` from mysql result. Until now I used the following

get_result.sh

```
echo "$1" |  mysql -u $user -p$pass -h $host --batch --quick --skip-column-names db | sed 's/\<NULL\>/\\N/g' > /tmp/file
```

And in many scripts I just call it, for example:

```
./get_result.sh "select * from table_with_null_values"
```

I found a bug in the above where `NULL` text would also get replaced. So I was thinking maybe on something like `sed 's/\tNULL\t>/\\N/g'` but even then, a text field can have this combo.
Of course an `ifnull` over each column in each script can help solved it. But i'm looking for something more elegant that doesn't requires a full change to my scripts.

**EDIT**
An example:

```
MYSQL> create table test(id int, a text, b text);
MYSQL> insert into test values(1,'a');
MYSQL> insert into test values(2,'NULL',null);
MYSQL> insert into test values(3,'\tNULL\t',null);
MYSQL> insert into test values(4,null,null);
]$ ./get_result.sh "select * from test"
]$ cat /tmp/file
1       a       NULL
2       NULL    NULL
2       \tNULL\t        NULL
4       NULL    NULL
```

Some things I've noticed:

1. `\tNULL\t` will not work as the null might be at the start/end.
2. tabs converted to `\t` just like new lines.
3. null values and string looks the same.

Comment: Surely if the word `NULL` appeared as text - i.e. at the beginning of a `VARCHAR ()` field, it wouldn't appear as `\tNULL\t` but rather `\t'NULL'\t`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace null with 0 in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532776/replace-null-with-0-in-mysql)

Comment: doing this in the query seems a lot more sensible as you get IS NULL handling,  treating 'null' as a string is always a bad idea! Ask Mr and Mrs Null.

Comment: @JeffUK He know he can do that, but he wants to select * on his query. That was my first thought too though... "Of course an ifnull over each column in each script can help solved it"

Comment: the sed 's/\tNULL\t>/\\N/g' is your best choice, don't forget to add the Tabs you're replacing as well - What are the odds a user would enter tab null tab in any text field?. So sed 's/\tNULL\t>/\t\\N\t/g'

Comment: @HenriqueDonati , `select *` is also a bad idea unless you really need to.

Comment: Does `perl -pe 's/(?:\t|^)\KNULL(?=\t|$)/\\N/g'` work for you?

Comment: that's what I was aiming from the other question. I will do performance testing and check which one is best. however, it doesn't solve the problem where someone enter `NULL` as a value.

Comment: What do you mean? That pattern also matches `NULL` typed in as a whole string.

Comment: Yeah, the mysql client return both identical. the perl command is what I was looking for but I need to figure out as well how to handle literal `NULL` value.